# Can any on solves the error my node is 17.5.0 and discord .js : 13.8.1

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
const { PREFIX } = require('../../JSON/config.json');
module.exports = {
  name: 'setstatus',
execute(client, message, args ) {


if(message.author.id !== '621333274480082945') return message.channel.send("**❌ لا تــــــملك الــــــصلاحية**")
        
        if(!args) return message.reply("اكــــتب الـــــحالة الــــجديدة")
     message.channel.send("تــــم ✅ <@621333274480082945>").then(message => {
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 2000)
        })
     client.user.setActivity(args)

      
}
}
```

the error :

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied activities[0].name is not a string.
    at ClientPresence._parse (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ClientPresence.js:51:54)
    at ClientPresence.set (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ClientPresence.js:22:25)    at ClientUser.setPresence (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ClientUser.js:120:33)
    at ClientUser.setActivity (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ClientUser.js:167:17)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\commands\Owner\status.js:14:18)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\events\messageCreate.js:12:26)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\handlers\events.js:10:54)
    at Client.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Downloads\Eissa.jsHandlerV13\Rocket $ Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
```

Comment: The error clearly refers to `activities[0].name` but we cannot see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: `args` is most likely a string array, where as `.setActivity()` takes a string.

Comment: I think you meant to use either `client.user.setActivity(args[0])` or `client.user.setActivity(args.join(' '))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `args` array to the `.setActivity()` method.
In order to solve your error, you need to pass a variable of type string in the `.setActivity()` method, probably `args[0]` or `args.join(" ")` in your case.

Also, you should probably use `if (args.length === 0)` (talking from experience).

```
if(message.author.id !== '621333274480082945') return message.channel.send("**❌ لا تــــــملك الــــــصلاحية**");
    
if(args.length === 0) return message.reply("اكــــتب الـــــحالة الــــجديدة");
message.channel.send("تــــم ✅ <@621333274480082945>").then(message => {
    setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 2000);
});

client.user.setActivity(args.join(" "));
```